# How to remove a line with a certain character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a text like this

```
'
blabla
blablab $!TOBEREMOVED
blabla
```

'

I want to remove every lines having '$!' .

therefore my example become that

```
'
blabla
blabla
```

'

I would like to use something like that:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (inhalt,'(' || chr(10) || '.$!.' || chr(10) || ')',''
```

It doesn't remove the line. The problem is that $ allready means something for regex.
Is there a way to delete the lines with '$!' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT inhalt,
       TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(inhalt, '(^|' || chr(10) || ').*\$!.*($|' ||
           chr(10) || ')', chr(10))) AS inhalt_out
FROM yourTable;
```